# MediaWiki: Graph of page relations extension

Tags: graph, dependencies, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am searching for a MediaWiki extension which, in an ideal world, should allow the following:

1. Each page should include a list of other pages related to it (let's call them dependencies).
2. The dependency tree of a given page, showing its dependencies recursively (that is, the direct dependencies, the dependencies of the direct dependencies, etc) should be displayed on the page.
3. Registered users should be able to mark pages as read/unread which should be reflected in the dependency trees (say, by changing the color of the nodes).

So far, I have found the following:

- A nice [implementation](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) of a tree graph  through [JIT](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) and a [MediaWiki plugin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PerformanceMonitor) using it (for completely different purposes though).
- The [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) which seems to handle the relational structure in some way, however, not exactly the way, I am searching for. It assigns properties to Wiki pages rather than linking pages together. I'm not sure whether this can be used to do generate the dependency tree.
- [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/), not sure, what exactly it does and how to use it, but somehow seems related to structuring data in a wiki.

Now I am a bit lost which way to follow and how to put the pieces together to achieve the desired result. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Of course, a ready to use solution (not necessarily in the form of a MediaWiki extension) would be even better!

Comment: Your description is lacking the critical bit, i.e. what defines "related". If you just mean links, then you need something that represents the whole [pagelinks table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table).

Comment: "Related" is defined by "needed in order to understand the given page". An implementation of this idea is for example the German Ubuntu portal ubuntuusers.de. In its wiki (which uses a self made software called Inyoka) each article carries a list of dependencies, here is an example: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/SSH/

Comment: Technically, these should be "special" links. In the example linked above they are collected into a list and not linked directly inside the text, only anchors are used to jump from a reference inside the text to the list. The idea is that the reader first makes himself familiar with the dependencies and then reads the given article rather than follows a lot of links while reading the article.